# Openstack Compute node not getting listed in hypervisor list

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, devstack

I’m trying to setup a multi-node OpenStack environment with OVS-DPDK. Unfortunately I’m running into issue that compute node not getting listed in hypervisor list as below screenshot. Due to this I’m unable to create instances on compute node.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

```
ubuntu@os-controller:~$ openstack compute service list
+----+------------------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID | Binary           | Host          | Zone     | Status  | State | Updated At                 |
+----+------------------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
|  3 | nova-scheduler   | os-controller | internal | enabled | up    | 2019-07-17T06:09:17.000000 |
|  9 | nova-consoleauth | os-controller | internal | enabled | up    | 2019-07-17T06:09:16.000000 |
| 10 | nova-conductor   | os-controller | internal | enabled | up    | 2019-07-17T06:09:17.000000 |
|  1 | nova-conductor   | os-controller | internal | enabled | up    | 2019-07-17T06:09:17.000000 |
|  2 | nova-compute     | os-controller | nova     | enabled | up    | 2019-07-17T06:09:12.000000 |
|  3 | nova-compute     | os-compute-01 | nova     | enabled | up    | 2019-07-17T06:09:17.000000 |
+----+------------------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
```

```
ubuntu@os-controller:~$ openstack hypervisor list 
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
| ID | Hypervisor Hostname | Hypervisor Type | Host IP      | State |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
|  1 | os-controller       | QEMU            | 10.210.126.6 | up    |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
```

Openstack version: Stein, Linux OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new compute nodes which should be visible in "$openstack hypervisor list" command, you need to change your "compute count" parameter every time in 00.nova.yaml environment template directory. Also, you need to see the configuration in Openstack Platform Director in the current plan (See plan name first) & redeploy the overcloud then.

NOTE: Please watch for the number of associated compute nodes in nodes section of the plan.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved once I did discover_hosts.sh on controller. as mentioned in below link.

https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/multinode-lab.html

A stream of activity ensues. When complete you will see a summary of stack.sh’s work, including the relevant URLs, accounts and passwords to poke at your shiny new OpenStack. The most recent log file is available in stack.sh.log.

Starting in the Ocata release, Nova requires a Cells v2 deployment. Compute node services must be mapped to a cell before they can be used.

After each compute node is stacked, verify it shows up in the nova service-list --binary nova-compute output. The compute service is registered in the cell database asynchronously so this may require polling.

Once the compute node services shows up, run the ./tools/discover_hosts.sh script from the control node to map compute hosts to the single cell.

The compute service running on the primary control node will be discovered automatically when the control node is stacked so this really only needs to be performed for subnodes.